# Remove warning on Node.js WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am learning backend with Node.js and using middleware to catch for errors and send a different response code and body.

[image: Unresolved function or method 'status()']

The warning is similar to err.message.

How do I remove these warnings?

Comment: I'm guessing you could start using some type definitions - either `.d.ts` files (such can be provided by `@types/express`) or JSDoc. IMO the former is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `express`? Its methods are generated dynamically in runtime, so they can't be resolved during static code analysis. Installing TypeScript stubs should help to get methods work: put cursor on `'express'` in `const express = require('express');` , hit `Alt+Enter` and choose **Install TypeScript definitions for better type information** to install typings - see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_jsconfigure_libraries_ts_definition_files